# Why does adding a computed to an observableArray fail?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I think something is very wrong here. I would like to add a `ko.computed` to a `ko.observableArray` like this.

Before that my model for clarity

```
//var job = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.job));
//var customer = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.customer));
//var estimateMaterials = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.estimateMaterials));
//var estimate = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.estimate));
var estimateTasks = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tasks));

var JobPostViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    //self.customer = ko.observable(customer);
    //self.job = ko.observable(job);
    //self.estimateMaterials = ko.observableArray(estimateMaterials);
    //self.estimate = ko.observable(estimate);
    self.estimateTasks = ko.observableArray(estimateTasks);
    self.estimateTasks().estLaborSubTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        return (isNaN(self.EstHr)? 0: +self.EstHr) * (isNaN(self.TaskPerHourCost)? 0: +self.TaskPerHourCost);
    });
};
var model = new JobPostViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model,  document.getElementById("my_job_form"));
```

So this is what my model bind is. `my_job_form` is `data-bind="with:jobs"` and I am populating a table inside the form that is bound to `estimateTasks`.  The markup is

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.estimateTasks">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: EstHr" />
            <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: TaskPerHourCost" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: estLaborSubTotal" disabled />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

On bind, I get the error

> ReferenceError: estLaborSubTotal is not defined

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check the answer I posted, I think it will be a bit simplier to read and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding an computed to an array.  This array is just the result of the evaluation of estimateTasks observableArray();

If I understand what you are trying to do.

You better do it this way.
This will add an computed named estLaborSubTotal to item.

```
var JobPostViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(estimateTasks, function(et) {
        et.estLaborSubTotal  = ko.computed({
            read: function(){
                var estHr = this.EstHr();
                var taskPerHourCost =  this.TaskPerHourCost();
                if(estHr === null)
                    return 0;
                return estHr * taskPerHourCost; 
            },
            owner : et // specify the "this" during evaluation 
        });
    });

    self.estimateTasks = ko.observableArray(estimateTasks);
};
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9yYU5/2/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: did not help me, what did you mean by `// specify the "this" during evaluation `

Comment: @naveen what exactly are you trying to do ? Please have a to 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html.

Comment: i am creating an observable array from a javascript array. and foreach element in that array, i am trying to add a new `ko.computed`

Comment: That's exactly what my code does. But I just add the computed on each item before creating the observable array.

Comment: thats why it aint working i guess. you are adding ko.computed to a javascript array and making the whole thing ko.observable again

Comment: I added a fiddle. Please tell me what is not working.

Comment: the fiddle aint working. i wanna change `estLaborSubTotal` when `EstHr` changes...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are trying to do -

```
function jobPostEstimateTaskModel (task) {
    var self = this;
    // Make some properties of this task observable
    self.name = ko.observable(task.name);
    // Make a computed for each task
    self.estLaborSubTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        return (isNaN(self.EstHr)? 0: +self.EstHr) * (isNaN(self.TaskPerHourCost)? 0: +self.TaskPerHourCost);
    });
}

var JobPostViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.estimateTasks = ko.observableArray();
    $.each(estimateTasks, function (index, item) {
        self.estimateTasks.push(new jobPostEstimateTaskModel(item));
    }
};
```

This will iterate through the estimateTasks plain old JavaScript array that you have created and add a new jobPostEstimateTaskModel object for each task in the array.  It will create observable properties on the task such as name in this example, and then create a computed for *each* item in the array.

By calling it the way you were above you are simply creating a computed onto the observableArray, and not doing what you intended.

One of the confusion points is that your ViewModel has an object that is an observableArray called estimateTasks but you also have a variable at the context 'above' it named the exact same thing.  Consider renaming your non-observable to something like estimateTasksJson to clarify.

**Edit**

Another way to approach this is to use prototyping - you would still need to instantiate an object like jobPostEstimateTaskModel or whatever you want to call it but you could extend an observable onto each instance without having to iterate through that code each time and add it in the model.

Comment: did not work. two way binding ain't happening. no observables at `httpPost`

Comment: This actually works perfectly, as does Damien's answer, you just aren't showing your code in a fiddle or anything else and we can't MAKE you use it right : )

Comment: dude i was away. i saw another answer posted by you on the same issue. thanks for spending your time for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that inside `foreach` current binding content is current array element.
And this element does not have `estLaborSubTotal` property.
You can use `<input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.estimateTasks().estLaborSubTotal" disabled />` instead.

Or you can change your viewmodel:

```
var JobPostViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    //self.customer = ko.observable(customer);
    //self.job = ko.observable(job);
    //self.estimateMaterials = ko.observableArray(estimateMaterials);
    //self.estimate = ko.observable(estimate);
    self.estimateTasks = ko.observableArray(estimateTasks);
    self.estLaborSubTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        return (isNaN(self.EstHr)? 0: +self.EstHr) * (isNaN(self.TaskPerHourCost)? 0: +self.TaskPerHourCost);
    });
};
```

And use `<input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.estLaborSubTotal" disabled />`.

Comment: agreed. but how do i bind it back when posting to server? that troubles me. how will it be in `var estTasks= [];`

Comment: Where in your json posted back to server you should place `estLaborSubTotal`? Should it be inside estimateTasks array?